# Can't seem to close previously opened elements with JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have personnel images on a website that when clicked is supposed to open a profile panel. This works as it should but if I click on another image without clicking the close button it will open the correct panel but it opens underneath the currently opened panel. I'm trying to figure out how to close the currently opened panel before opening the new one.

I have tried toggling a show-content class, that changes the display property, with jQuery and JS. This did not even show the panel properly. I have also tried to remove the class and display property before finding the profile-panel id and setting the class, with no success.

The code below is the current code that will pull up the profile-panel like it should but it will not close the opened one when I click another image, leaving the new panel covered.

My relevant **HTML** code:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
  <a href="#Jane" onclick="openProfile()">
    <img class="profile-pic" src="/images/uploads/test-image.jpg">
    <div class="name-overlay" onclick="openProfile('Jane', '1')">
      <h2>Jane Doe</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
  <a href="#John" onclick="openProfile()">
    <img class="profile-pic" src="/images/uploads/test-image-2.jpg">
    <div class="name-overlay" onclick="openProfile('John', '2')">
      <h2>John Doe</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

My relevant **CSS** code:

```
.profile-panel { position: absolute; display: none; }
```

My relevant **JS** code:

```
var slideIndex;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("profile-panel");

function plusSlides() {
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  else if(slideIndex < 1){slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "flex";
  console.log(slideIndex);
}

function minusSlides() {
  slideIndex--;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  else if(slideIndex < 1){slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "flex";
  console.log(slideIndex);
}

function openProfile(id, number) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "flex";
  slideIndex = number;
}

function closeProfile(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: When you open one of the panels, close all of the other ones beforehand, like `slides.forEach(function(p) { p.style.display = 'none'; });` at the start of your `openProfile` function (adapt to better backward-compatible code if needed — one liners fit better in a SO comment, is all).

Comment: `$(".profile-panel").hide()`.  You've tagged this jquery but doesn't look like you're using jquery.

Comment: Where is `profile-panel` on the html? Where is `plusSlides`, `minusSlides` and `closeProfile` being called? Why `openProfile` is being called twice, one on the `a` with no arguments and one on the `div`? Where is your jQuery code? Please edit your question to clarify this.